# How to represent a constraint on the kth-smallest function?

Tags: modeling, constraint

How can I represent the following set of constraints in a linear program, where $c_1,\ldots, c_n$ are constants and $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ are functions of the optimization variables?

> The smallest of $f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x)$ is at least $c_1$;
>
> The second-smallest of $f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x)$ is at least $c_2$;
>
> The third-smallest of $f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x)$ is at least $c_3$;
>
> ...
>
> The largest of $f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x)$ is at least $c_n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first constraint is convex, and can be handled without use of logical constraints or introduction of binary variables:
$$f_1(x) \ge c_1, ..., f_n(x) \ge c_1$$

The remaining constraints are non-convex, and so require logical constraints or binary variables to handle.

For simplicity of exposition, I will assume logical constraints are available. If not, they can be handled by standard big M modeling, such as in the "If $f(x)\le0$ then a" section of [Logics and integer-programming representations](https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/logicprogramming), or as found on this site.

For each $k$ from $2$ to $n$, and for each $i$ from $1$ to $n$, let $b_{k,i}$ be a binary variable, and specify the logical constraints
$$b_{k,i} = 1 \implies f_i(x) \ge c_k.$$ For each $k$ from $2$ to $n$, impose the constraint: $$\sum_{i=1}^n b_{k,i} \ge n-k+1$$

**Edit**: I corrected a typo and improved the formulation, both as pointed out in the comments by @RobPratt. By switching the direction (specifying the contrapositive) of the logic constraints, the need for an $\epsilon$ fudge factor was eliminated.

Comment: Your $f_n(x) \ge c_n$ should instead be $f_n(x) \ge c_1$, right?  Also, it seems like you can avoid $\epsilon$ by instead imposing $b_{k,i}=1 \implies f_i(x) \ge c_k$.

Comment: @RobPratt. Agree on both counts, which have now been incorporated. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent to say that there exists a permutation of $c_i$, say $c_{(i)}$, that satisfies
$$
f_i(x) \geq c_{(i)},\quad \forall i=1,\dots, n
$$

The permutation $c_{(i)}$ could be expressed with a permutation matrix
$$
f_i(x) \geq \sum_{j} b_{ij}c_{j},\quad\forall i\\
\sum_{i} b_{ij} = 1,\quad\forall j\\
\sum_{j} b_{ij} = 1,\quad\forall i\\
b_{ij} \in \{0, 1\},\quad\forall i, j
$$

Edit: After testing, my formulation is correct but it is significantly slower than the model in the previous answer.