# Robust Optimization in Gurobi

Tags: optimization, gurobi, stochastic-programming, robust-optimization

I have a research problem where my Mixed Integer Linear Program has data that follow probability distributions. I am approaching this by creating some m instances through realizations of these random variables (data).

How do I approach this problem in Gurobi?

For a better explanation, my data will be simple numerical data once the random variables are realized. But I will have created 1000 such instances and I want my model to perform optimally on say the 75th quantile case.

Comment: Is the uncertainty in the constraint RHSs, the objective function, the constraint matrix, or everywhere?

Comment: @Max the uncertainty is in the objective function only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is to rewrite the objective somewhat.

I'm going to start from an objective of the following form:
$$ \min_x c(\zeta)^\top x, $$
with $c(\zeta)$ a cost vector depending on a random vector $\zeta$ with known probability distribution, and $x$ a decision vector, both of suitable dimension.

Now, the problem using $\zeta$ directly is that the support of its probability distribution could be very large. Instead, we can sample a representative set of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ realisations $\zeta_1, \zeta_2, \ldots, \zeta_n$ from the probability distribution of $\zeta$.
If these samples adequately capture the randomness in $\zeta$, the resulting sampling solution should also be close to the optimal solution had we used $\zeta$ directly.

We can restate the sampling objective using an epigraph formulation, as
$$ \min_{x, t} t $$
with $t \in \mathbb{R}$, subject to
$$ t \ge c(\zeta_i)^\top x, \qquad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n. $$

Using binary variables $z_i \in \{0, 1\}$ for $i = 1,\ldots, n$, we can rewrite this to add the condition that a fraction $\alpha \in [0,1]$ of these constraints may be violated:
\begin{align} \textstyle
  \sum_{i = 1}^n z_i &\le \alpha n, \\
  t &\ge c(\zeta_i)^\top x - Mz_i \qquad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n,
\end{align}
for some $M$ big enough. A concrete value for $M$ could be the objective value you get when optimising with $M = \alpha = 0$.

For the $0.75$ quantile, set $\alpha = 0.25$.

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me. Although my objective is maximization, I can at least see potential modifications. I would like to learn more about such formulations, do you have a resource that you can guide me to if possible?

Comment: @arvind rathoe My answer shows modification for maximization.

Comment: @arvindrathore I got quite a bit out of the _Introduction to Stochastic Programming_ book by Birge and Louveaux, who deal with many of these types of problems. Since you're dealing with probability distributions, this might be a good fit.

Additionally, perhaps _Robust and Adaptive Optimization_ by Bertsimas and Den Hertog could be nice to get a very different perspective on 'optimisation under uncertainty'. Between those two books, many methods for dealing with uncertainty should be covered.

Answer (score 6):

The following formulation is more or less the same as the formulation used in [How to represent a constraint on the kth-smallest function?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8633/how-to-represent-a-constraint-on-the-kth-smallest-function/8634#8634). So thanks to @RobPratt for providing a comment which improved that formulation, and hence this one.

Le $N$ be the number off scenarios. In your case, 1000.

Let $q$ be the applicable quantile. In your case, 0.75

Let $f(i)$ be the non-robustified objective value for scenario $i$.

Declare an optimization variable $t$, which will be the objective function to be minimized in the robustified problem.

Declare $b$ as a vector of $N$ binary optimization variables.

Add the indicator constraints:

$b(i) = 1 \rightarrow f(i) \le t$ for $i=1,...,N$

(If maximizing instead of minimizing, instead use
$b(i) = 1 \rightarrow f(i) \ge t$ for $i=1,...,N$)

Add the constraint $\Sigma_{i=1}^N b(i) \ge q N$

If this were implemented in a modeling system (and solver other than Gurobi) which did not have indicator constraints, the Big M equivalent could be used instead.

Comment: Whoops, didn't see @Nelewout 's answer until after I posted this.  I'll leave my answer up for now, as it might be somewhat cleaner and clearer., especially given the availability of indicator functions in Gurobi.

Comment: Once I tried a chance constrained example like above and, to me, it worked.

Comment: @Sutanu This is not really chance-constrained.  The "chance", meaning quantile, is in the objective function. However, my formulation moves the "chance" to the constraints as epigraph formulation for handle quantile in objective.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone just for my edification: do you know how Gurobi implements indicator constraints under the hood? I'd imagine that's something big-M-like as well, but would be interested to learn if they do something clever!

Comment: Gurobi does not convert indicator constraints into Big M.  You can read the entire thread https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/231/when-to-use-indicator-constraints-versus-big-m-approaches-in-solving-mixed-int for some insight as to how various solvers, including Gurobi, implement indicator constraints, and numerical differences vs. Big M. You may need a Gurobi employee to provide more detailed information. on Gurobi's implementation, and I don't now how forthcoming they would be in providing possibly proprietary details.

Answer (score 2):

Robust optimization ($+/-$) is still a research area and I am not sure if Gurobi has an automated way unless you want to follow this example from [Wolfram](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RobustConvexOptimization.html#:%7E:text=Robust%20optimization%20is%20typically%20used,for%20all%20possible%20parameter%20values.). In case it's [stochastic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_programming) one way is to apply sample approximation average ([SAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_programming#Monte_Carlo_sampling_and_Sample_Average_Approximation_(SAA)_Method)) if continuous distribution and parameters are known. You can generate sample data at cdf $\ge 75$% then take expected value of the sample. You can repeat this process itself. If you are using [chance constraints](https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Chance-constraint_method#:%7E:text=The%20chance%2Dconstraint%20method%20of,determining%20the%20most%20likely%20result.) then you may need to determine the z-score at $75$% and then use appropriate relation.
You can check [LINDO](http://www.lindo.com/cgi-bin/modelf.cgi?NewsVendScen01.txt;LINGO) example and [GAMS](https://www.gams.com/latest/gamslib_ml/libhtml/gamslib_chance.html) example

Comment: I think your answer would be more helpful, if you expanded it bit. For example, the magic constant "75" may seem odd without any explanation.

Comment: The OP put an example of 75th percentile or probability 75% which in a normal dist is around 0.67 z-score.

Comment: I think I forgot to add an important detail. My data uncertainty is limited to only the objective function. In this case, is there a known way of solving any kind of solver? This is not a novel part of my research so I am hoping to reduce my workload on this.