# How to set up a constraint that represents a median?

Tags: constraint

I'm trying to create an optimization problem where one of my constraints represents a median of another decision variable. Suppose I have decision variables $\bf{y}$ and $z$. My problem will look something like:

\begin{align}\min &\quad f(z)\\\ \text{s.t.} &\quad\text{constraint that defines z to be the median value of y}\\\ 
&\quad [\text{other constraints with y}]\end{align}

I'm not sure how to express this constraint. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an odd number of $y$ variables?

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8633/how-to-represent-a-constraint-on-the-kth-smallest-function/8634#8634

Comment: Following up on @RobPratt's question, if $y$ has even dimension do you need $z$ to be the mean of the two middle $y$ values are just anything between the two middle values?

Comment: @RobPratt I'd like to set it up such that the code works whether we have an odd or even number of variables, if possible.

Comment: @prubin If there are an even number of variables, I'd need $z$ to be the mean of the two middle values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have an odd number of variables $y_1,\dots,y_{2k+1}$.  Introduce binary variables $u_i$ and $v_i$ to indicate whether $z \ge y_i$ or $z \le y_i$, respectively.  Now impose constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_i u_i &= k+1 \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_i v_i &= k+1 \tag2\label2 \\
u_i = 1 &\implies z \ge y_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag3\label3 \\
v_i = 1 &\implies z \le y_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag4\label4
\end{align}
You can linearize the indicator constraints \eqref{3} and \eqref{4} via big-M constraints:
\begin{align}
y_i - z &\le M(1-u_i) &&\text{for all $i$} \tag{3'}\label{3'} \\
z - y_i &\le M(1-v_i) &&\text{for all $i$} \tag{4'}\label{4'}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, this looks great! My initial ideas to solve this were much more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

First you may need to sort your optimization variables. Taking idea from Dr. Kalvelagen ([link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/12/sorting-inside-mip-model.html)) & [YALMIP](https://yalmip.github.io/example/weightedsort/) define additional continuous variable $0 z$, $x$ of same domain s $y$ & $i \times i$ matrix of binary variables $p$

Basically
$x_i = p_{i,j}x_i$

$\sum_i z_{i,j} = y_j \quad \forall j$
$\sum_j z_{i,j} = x_i \quad \forall i$
$\sum_i p_{i,j} = 1$
$\sum_j p_{i,j} = 1$
$x_i \le x_{i+1}$
$z_{i,j} \le Mp_{i,j}$

Median = $x_{I+1\over2}$ if $I$ or $J$ is odd, else ${x_{k}+x_{k+1}}\over 2$ where $k={{I}\over2}$

Comment: I think you meant something else instead of $x_i=p_{i,j}x_i$, which would imply that $p_{i,j}=1$ or $x_i=0$.  Also, we are not given that $y_i \ge 0$, so you should not impose $x_i \ge 0$.

Comment: Also, you want $k=I/2$ in the even case.

Comment: Nice links. ...